# prove that $C_{c}^\infty\subset \mathcal{S}$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

In this exercice $C_{c}^\infty$ denotes the set of all functions defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are infinitely differentiable and compactly supported and let us remember how the space of Schwartz. A multi-index $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d)$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}_{0}^d$, where $\mathbb{N}_0=\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$, and the order of the multi-index $\alpha$ is the number
$$|\alpha|=\sum_{j=1}^d\alpha_j.$$
Additionally we introduce the following notations:
$$x^\alpha:=x_{1}^{\alpha_1}x_{2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_{d}^{\alpha_d},$$
$$\partial^\alpha:=\partial_{x_1}^{\alpha_1}\partial_{x_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots \partial_{x_d}^{\alpha_d},\quad \mbox{where}\hspace{.1cm} \partial_{x_i}^{\alpha_i}\hspace{.1cm} \mbox{denotes the operator}\hspace{.1cm}\frac{\partial^{\alpha_i}}{\partial x_{i}^{\alpha_i}},$$
$$f^{(\alpha)}:=\partial^\alpha f,$$
provided that the derivatives of $f$ exist. In case that $x_i=\alpha_i=0$ for some $i\in\{1,...,d\}$, for convenience we will assume that in the expression $x^\alpha$ the term $x_{i}^{\alpha_i}$ is equal to 1.

***Definition (Schwartz space).*** The Schwartz space, denoted by $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, is the set formed by all functions $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that
$$\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}:=\displaystyle{\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}}\left|x^\alpha f^{(\beta)}(x)\right|<\infty\qquad\mbox{for all}\hspace{.1cm} \alpha, \beta\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^d.$$
The Schwartz space is also known as the space of infinitely differentiable functions of rapid decrease.

The idea I have to try this exercise is the following: ***let $f\in C_{c}^\infty$, then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and therefore $f$ and its partial derivatives are bounded in each compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.*** *From this point I don't know how to proceed to conclude that $ f\in \mathcal{S}$.*

Comment: The point is that the $\sup$ in the definition of $\| f\|_{\alpha,\beta}$, for $f\in C_c^\infty$, can be taken over a compact set $K$ (depending only on $f$), but then on $K$ we have $|x|^\alpha$ is bounded and so...

Comment: Prove that if $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is supported on $K$, then $\partial_{x_j}f$ is also supported on $K$. By induction, every multi-index derivative of $f$ is supported on $K$.